# Trigger to copy child object picklist values to parent object separated by comma

Tags: apex, trigger

I have picklist field "Location" on opportunity object and text field "Type" on Account object. I want to copy the picklist values from all opportunities related to the account and display it on "Type" field on account separated by comma. I tried using process builder but didn't work, tried using below trigger but not working, any help?

trigger UpdateAmount on Opportunity (after insert, after update) { 
  Map parentOpps = new Map(); 
  Set listIds = new Set();

for (Opportunity childObj : Trigger.new) {
    listIds.add(childObj.AccountId);
  }

parentOpps = new Map([SELECT id, Opp_Location__c ,
                                        (SELECT ID,Location_Type__c  FROM Opportunities) 
                                    FROM Account WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

List lstAccount = new List();

for(Account acct:parentOpps.values())
  {
      List strType = new List();
      for(Opportunity oppty:acct.Opportunities)
      {
          strType.add(oppty.Opp_Location__c);
      }
      acct.Location_Type__c = String.join(strType,',');

}

update parentOpps.values();
}

Answer (score 2):

The code you have shared will not at all compile.

- use close brace here `for (Opportunity childObj : Trigger.new)`
- use `childObj.AccountId` instead of `childObj.Account` to access AccountId
- When you use relationship query be sure to use `Opportunities` instead of `Opportunity`.
- You should put Opportunity's `Opp_Location__c` into a List. Then use `String.join()` to add those with comma delimited.
- And finally update accounts.

**Trigger**

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Opportunity (after insert, after update) { 
  Map<ID, Account > parentOpps = new Map<ID, Account>(); 
  Set<Id> listIds = new Set<Id>();

  for (Opportunity childObj : Trigger.new) {
    listIds.add(childObj.AccountId);
  }

  parentOpps = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id, Location_Type__c ,
                                        (SELECT ID, Opp_Location__c  FROM Opportunities) 
                                    FROM Account WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

  List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();

  for(Account acct:parentOpps.values())
  {  
      List<String> strType = new List<String>();
      for(Opportunity oppty:acct.Opportunities)
      {
          strType.add(oppty.Opp_Location__c);
      }
      acct.Location_Type__c = String.join(strType,',');

  }

  update parentOpps.values();
}
```

Comment: Sorry pretty new to apex, is it possible to update the code?

Comment: I have given the approach, feel free to change according to your need

Comment: May not apply to this situation, but if multiple opportunities on the same account are likely to have the same value in Opp_Location__c, then you can dedupe them by making strType a Set instead of a List and then setting acct.Location_Type__c = String.join(new List<String>(strType),',');

Comment: I get error Compile Error: Invalid field Opp_Location__c for SObject Opportunity at line 20 column 23

Comment: you could check the correct API of the respective object

Comment: @Santanu, this is gold. It works brilliantly.